# jquery - find how many textareas have been submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a form which contains 3 textareas. What I'd like to do is to find how many textareas the user has fullfiled, so that an alert message should warn the user each time that has left n-fields without submiting, something like:

`"details missing for 2 out of 3 fields" // when submiting only the first one`

`"details missing for 1 out of 3 fields" // when submiting the first two text areas`
etc etc

This is my script

```
$('textarea[name="area1"]').on('keyup', function () {
                $('#opt-remain').text($('#opt-remain').text()-1)
            });
            $('textarea[name="area2"]').on('keyup', function () {
                $('#opt-remain').text($('#opt-remain').text()-1)
            });
            $('textarea[name="area3"]').on('keyup', function () {
                $('#opt-remain').text($('#opt-remain').text()-1)
            });

<div id="optional-alert" class="alert alert-warning" style="display:none; margin-bottom:0">
(<span id="opt-remain"></span> out of 3)
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify this by doing

```
$('form textarea').change(function() {
    $('#optional-alert').show();
    var count = $('form textarea').filter(function(textarea) {
        return ! $(this).val();
    }).length;
    $('#opt-remain').text(count);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xktm3cwe/

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't explain correct what I 'm trying to do, please review the post

Comment: Try removing the `:not()` to select the empty ones : `$('form textarea:empty')`

Comment: Doesn't work.. the alert pops up (as expected) saying: "details missing in 3 out of 3 fields", but when I submit the 1st area, the number does not reduce (i.e. 2 out of 3) etc etc

Comment: same also with `:not()`

Comment: you're correct, it didn't work, now it should be good, see the fiddle